# Large Scale lightning Strikes from Cloudless or Near Coudless Skies. How Does it Work?

Tags: meteorology, lightning, drought, wildfire

It is reported in the media that currently in Australia there are dozens of wildfires caused by lightning strikes. I am familiar with the mechanism of ordinary British lightning involving cumulonimbus and moisture, but I don't understand the Australian mechanism where hot,bone dry conditions cause lightning strikes on a massive scale, apparently from cloudless or near cloudless skies. The role of high temperatures and near cloudless skies obviously makes vegetation highly inflammable, but solar radiation hot enough to heat it to ignition temperature would kill everyone in Australia, so contrary to what some people appear to believe it can't be that. Perhaps someone can offer an explanation.

Comment: This is interesting. I once was tought that a lighting can travel some distance horizontally and hit the ground away from the thunderstorm. My interpretation is that these strikes were rather thunderstorms from frontal systems moving in than "clear air" strikes. Are the any links that describe what happened ?

Comment: Example: https://live.staticflickr.com/7667/17059820722_d3cc2ecd36_b.jpg

Comment: This looks suspiciously like conventional cumulonimbus which I already understand. As I said in my question, it is the moisture-free Australian lightning which needs explanation.

Comment: I think the problem might be the assumption of completely cloudless skies.  The western US is, I'm told, quite similar to much of Australia.  While skies here are generally clear in summer, and the relative humidity is low, quite often cumulonimbus clouds build up in the afternoon, leading to lightning that sparks wildfires.  There may not be rain associated with these clouds, or the rain may not reach the ground (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virga ) The storms can also be scattered events, with plenty of clear sky between.

Comment: To make th comparison more valid you need to wit until there is a long drought in western USA which bakes the vegetation and makes it very combustible. In UK long droughts are accompanied  by day after day of clear skies, as in 1976 and in lesser droughts since..

Comment: @Michael Walsby: In the western US (or at least the Great Basin and adjacent parts), that period of long drought is called "summer".  Also quite often much of spring & fall: https://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/nevada/united-states/3198  FWIW, wildfires can happen any time of year.  I've had to evacuate for one in January.  (Started by careless disposal of fireplace ashes, though, not lightning.)

Comment: What I don't understand is why people living in fire prone areas allow trees and brush to grow right up to their back doors. surely, that's asking for trouble.

Comment: This fire https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/aug/09/canary-islands-fire-ravages-7-of-la-palma passed 500m by my house. There is nothing you can do, fire can jump over long distances because of strong winds. The answer is correct.

Comment: There are limits to how far fire can jump, and strong winds are not guaranteed.

Comment: @Michael Walsby: Of course there are limits, but those limits are further than you might think.  The local fire services state that embers from a fire can easily travel over a mile and start new fires.  I've seen it happen over about a quarter of that distance.

Comment: @jamesqf Your observations are correct and I have confirmed them with an expert !

Comment: A fire creates its own winds if it is intense enough. That's why firestorms are called firestorms. The updraft causes gales or hurricanes in the streets, and people are sucked or blown into the flames. That's why Dresden, Hamburg, Darmstadt etc were different from London. But the winds are from the periphery towards the centre of the fire. I wondered whether wildfires could reach that intensity. The updraft rises to great heights, rather like a cumulonimbus cloud..

Answer (score 6):

**Revised answer**

**TL;DR** After having just heard from two experts who actually work in this field(firestorms and dry lightning) in Australia I believe the lightning seen is what is known as "[dry lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_thunderstorm)" comes from isolated thunderstorms and sometimes storms associated with minor troughs and fronts that come through Australia and also originating from a [pyrocumulonimbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulonimbus_flammagenitus) cloud. So @David Hammen and @jamesql are correct in their observations that the large scale dry lightning is indeed originating from isolated thunderstorms as well as storms associated with minor troughs and fronts. This dry lightning the experts confirm  is associated with little rain.

In addition **there have also been several  dry lightning strikes from pyrocumulonimbus clouds**. As an example for today over 20 dry lightning strikes have been recorded originating from pyrocumulonimbus clouds.

The major driver for the current drought like conditions over Australia is the large anomalous positive Indian Ocean Dipole ([positive IOD](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/iod/)) that has persisted well into boreal autumn/astral spring.

What the experts mention is that while the dry hot conditions are sporadic (2-4 days) they are persisting over over many weeks.

The following articles written by two researchers  [Firestorms and flaming tornadoes: how bushfires create their own ferocious weather systems](https://theconversation.com/firestorms-and-flaming-tornadoes-how-bushfires-create-their-own-ferocious-weather-systems-126832)
 and [Firestorms: the bushfire/thunderstorm hybrids we urgently need to understand](https://theconversation.com/firestorms-the-bushfire-thunderstorm-hybrids-we-urgently-need-to-understand-68426) provide information on the dynamics behind firestorms and the formation of pyrocumulus clouds and the associated dry lightning.

Following is a  summary of those articles and the conditions that lead to dry lightning from pyrocumulonimbus clouds.

Not all bushfires lead to firestorms. If a bushfire has sufficient area the upward movement of air causes the fire to interact with the atmosphere above it and form what is known as a pyrocloud. If in addition  there is an atmospheric instability then this process leads to the formation of a pyrocumulonimbus cloud . Normally in meteorology we are taught of heat radiating from the ground but in this case the upward movement of air is due to the heat emanating from the fire.

Again from mesoscale meteorology one hears the word "downdrafts". Similarly in this context the appropriate word is "downbursts" and these are vertical drafts of air that hit the ground and move about in all directions. The unsettled conditions cause embers to carry over large distances.

These firestorms produce dry lightning that potentially can spark new fires that may end up creating a larger flaming zone.

Comment: I don't disagree or quarrel with the answer, but it occurred to me that the firestorms in Dresden, Hamburg, Darmstadt, Tokyo and many other towns should have had the same effect, yet if it did I never heard about it. Were there any dry lightning storms over these towns? There were no firestorms in Britain, the bombing was not sufficiently intense.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby It appears from your multiple comments and answers/questions that you are obsessed with World War II. However I think the linked wikipedia article does suggest that Hiroshima and Nagasaki may have had possible pyrocumulonimbus clouds associated with it. Lightning one cannot confirm

Comment: Downvoted because you are taking the OP's claim that the lightning hitting Australia comes from cloudless skies as gospel truth. This is not the case. This is the time of year when Australia gets a lot of run of the mill (i.e., water-driven) thunderstorms.

Comment: @DavidHammen https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-50383800 BBC News seems to confirm it.  Your downvote is your personal choice. I am just explaining what OP asked for.  i am not making an assumption in my answer that Australia is having cloudless skies. I am explaining the mechanism behind bushfires and the associated lightning

Comment: IMO the downvote was a bit too quick. Though news have it that frontal/orographic (still partly dry) thunderstorms, child's play and malicious acts initiated fires, their uncontrolled spread is mostly due to dry lightning.

Comment: @ebv https://www.themercury.com.au/news/tasmania/multiple-wilderness-fires-caused-by-dry-lightning-strikes-burning-in-tasmanias-south-west/news-story/039b39162819e10524c3de6011f9bff8 yes and these dry lightning episodes as recent as a week ago

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102654/discussion-between-ebv-and-gansub). Edit: was just curious how this "automatic move" feature works. It does ... :-)

Comment: Hi. I think your update with OLR map overstates it as evidence for the OP's "lightning strikes on a massive scale, apparently from cloudless or near cloudless skies".  The climatological OLR anomaly shows less frequent convection/cloud, but you haven't made the link with actual lightning events.  Those dry lightning forecasts usually occur in a context of other regional weather (e.g., troughs, wet lightning).  There's a lot of meteorology going on in each case and there's a danger of us leaving readers with a misleadingly simple picture.

Comment: @Deditos I get your point. But Australia is going through a severe drought at the moment. Otherwise they would have their regular monsoon by this time. The ITCZ is still not convincingly over Australia. The climatological OLR anomaly is an indication of bad the drought has been.

Comment: @Deditos https://www.severe-weather.eu/news/unusually-strong-indian-ocean-dipole-australia-europe-fa/

Comment: ITCZ and monsoon are different things, guys. Does the first affect Australia at all ? And if i got it right it is not questioned that initial sparks came from regular, though possibly dry (water does not reach the ground) thunderstorms. These exist in Europe as well, though they are rare. I have no problem with that.

Comment: @ebv the ITCZ here is the monsoon trough. Yes the northern areas are affected by tropical weather every year. Frontal activity only affects mid latitudes of Australia. It is a big country.

Comment: @ebv: "Dry ligntning", at least as it happens here in the western US (never been to Australia) still comes from moisture-driven cumulonimbus clouds - that is, thunderstorms.  It's just that the vertical temperature-humidity profile is such that precipitation never happens, or never reaches the ground.

Comment: @jamesqf, yeah, these lightnings i know (first remark under OP). Also that clouds of all types can't hold back but it never reaches the ground. What was new for me is that a thundery cloud can form from a fire alone. Pretty impressive, huh ... :-)

Comment: @gansub Ah yes, I'm not disputing the wider context (IOD, severe drought, etc), it's the step to making statements about point events (lightning strikes) directly from that context that I'd query.  Browsing the satellite data for Nov/Dec suggests a more complicated picture, which fits with my experience of convection case studies in other semi-arid regions.  I think it just needs an edit, not deletion though.

Comment: @Deditos Yes acknowledged. I am having an expert look at this answer and then I will edit it appropriately. Please give me some time given the holidays etc.

Comment: @ebv: Sure, lightning from pyrocumulonimbus (and from volcanic eruptions) is interesting, but as an answer to starting Australian wildfires, I think it misses an important point, which is that you don't get a pyrocumulonimbus cloud unless you already have a fire.  And when you do have a fire, embers carried aloft by convection are far more effective in starting new fires. (Google says that of the ~20 million lightning strikes in the US each year, only about 9000 start fires.)

Comment: @MichaelWalsby https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/the-great-japan-earthquake-of-1923-1764539/ The first fire tornado was observed in a modern sense in 1923 and not WW II. End of discussion